# How to redirect HTTPS port 80 requests to Spring Boot backend server app on HTTPS port 8080 using reverse proxy?

Tags: https, proxy, backend, reverse

Installed/running:

- Spring Boot Java app running on the server reachable through https://:8080
- Apache

Problem:
Make the backend server and port reachable via the normal HTTPS port (443) by redirecting HTTPS requests (https:// or https://:443) to https://:8080

Answer (score 0):

This took quite a while to figure out. Key was to examine the log files, default location (var/log/apache2) and then concluded the key missing directives were

```
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
```

The complete instructions are as follows:

enable SSL

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

restart apache

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

generate self-signed certificate

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
```

generate a certificate signing request

```
sudo openssl req -nodes -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr
```

You should see the following output:

```
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:NL
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:NEDERLAND
Locality Name (eg, city) []:AMSTERDAM
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:ORG
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:IT
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:MYNAME
Email Address []:

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:
```

generate a self-signed certificate (ca.crt) of X509 type valid for 365 days

```
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ca.csr -signkey ca.key -out ca.crt
```

Create a directory to place the certificate files we have created.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apache2/ssl
```

Next, copy all certificate files to the /etc/apache2/ssl directory.

```
sudo cp ca.crt ca.key ca.csr /etc/apache2/ssl/
```

Now all the certificates are ready. The next thing to do is to set up the Apache to display the new certificate.

For this, you need to create new virtual host file proxy-ssl-host.conf

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy-ssl-host.conf
```

Add the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        #DocumentRoot /
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine On
        # Set the path to SSL certificate
        # Usage: SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.key
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse /alert https://127.0.0.1:8080/alert
        ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and close the file.

Enable new virtual host file:

```
sudo a2ensite proxy-ssl-host.conf
```

Now, restart the Apache service to make this change take effect:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

That’s it. You can now access your backend server using the URL
[https://<your server>](https://your.server)